# Could the `typeof` a type literal be considered a compile-time constant?

Tags: c#, typeof

I'm aware that currently, one cannot use a `typeof()` expression and have the compiler consider it compile-time constant in any context.

Unfortunately, that means we miss out on some nice options, for instance being able to switch on the `typeof(TGeneric)` and use `typeof(KnownType)` in our cases:

```
        public MyType MyGenericMethod<T>()
        {
            return typeof(T) switch
                {
                    typeof(KnownTypeA) => return A(),
                    typeof(KnownTypeB) => return B(),
                    typeof(KnownTypeC) => return C()
                };
        }
```

Now, we can work around that by switching on `typeof(T).Name` and using `nameof(KnownTypeA)` in our case. However, I really don't think this *should* be necessary. So, I'm considering opening a discussion on the [csharplang repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang).

Before I do this, I wanted to know if there's any situation in which `typeof(A.Known.Type)` could possibly not be determined at compile time?

Comment: FYI https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/356

Comment: If you show an example when that value could be determined at compile time (even ignoring the fact that result of the call is actually run-time object) it would make easier to figure out why you don't see common cases :)... Things like assembly redirects or seriously trolling way how ASP.Net hot-load updated types while debugging piling up tons of "identical" distinct types into single appdomain should jump into mind first before coming up with rare cases when you may know answer at compile time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `typeof` is actually turned by compiler into method call:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(List<object>));
```

is represented in IL with:

```
IL_0000: ldtoken class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<object>
IL_0005: call class [System.Runtime]System.Type [System.Runtime]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [System.Runtime]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
IL_000a: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
```

[@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYAYAEMEBYDcqqOAnABTACeADgKYD2AZmQDJgDOwAPPQEYBWtAMbAAfAEpx+IA===)

As for treating some expressions involving `typeof` as "constant ones" there are several suggestions already:

- [JIT: Make JIT time constants from calls to Type methods and properties](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/4920) (this one about performance and runtime constants)
- [Proposal: switch on `System.Type`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/356) (basically what you want)
- Comment for [Proposal: Compile time expressions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/1028#discussioncomment-72626)

Comment: Okay that's great, saves me suggesting it, however, your answer doesn't really tell me whether there is any reason this change couldn't really be made?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater 1. some changes definitely could be made 2. runtime does not load/compile all the types which are present in the libraries/projects used by the app but does it when needed, so strictly speaking type info is not a constant which can be embedded into the assembly. In general this is question of value over the cost of implementation.

Comment: @GuruStron probably is you mention that it's run-time that actually decides what to load for a give assembly (and correspondingly all its types) it would be easier for OP to understand the problem.